# Sed add forward-slash to beginning of line

Tags: linux, sed

Want to add a forward slash to the beginning of each line in a file. Having trouble escaping the character.

**Input**

```
// input.txt
hello
world
foo
bar
```

**Expected Output**

```
/hello
/world
/foo
/bar
```

**Command Tried**

```sh
cat input.txt | sed 's/^/\/\\/'
```

**Output of Command Tried**

```
/\hello
/\world
/\foo
/\bar
```

Any insights is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat input.txt | sed 's/^/\//'
/hello
/world
/foo
/bar
```

Comment:  thank you, upvoted and "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes"

Comment: i had this in my ctrl z'ing but forgot to add `sed` in front causing it to fail, facepalm.